# How to have Top and Bottom toolbar of different colors in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp

In one of the latest releases Xamarin.Forms added the possibility to place the toolbar at the bottom (`ToolBarPlacement`) and by setting the Property `BarBackgroundColor` on `NavigationPage` the background color of the toolbar can be changed.

Unfortunately, when the toolbar is split (as is the default on Windows 10 Mobile  or when `ToolbarPlacement` is bottom) both bars have the same background color.

In my app I want to achieve that the top bar (with title and hamburger menu) has the system's accent color and the bottom bar (with commands and flyout) is gray, as this combination is also used [by many system apps](https://mspoweruser.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/wp_ss_20150613_0004.png) (e.g. Mail or Calendar on Windows 10 Mobile).
But I cannot figure out how to do it without touching the core implementation in Xamarin.Forms. I already tried custom `NavigationPageRenderer` and custom `PageRenderer`, but many of the relevant fields are private, sealed or internal or are accessing internal interfaces.

The background colors of the two bars seem to be bound to the same property as changing the background of one bar in Visual Studio's Live XAML Tree View also changes the color of the other one.

Any help on how to achieve the desired look will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I achieved the desired result.

One of the problems was that my RootPage was a `MasterDetailPage`, so I had to create a `MasterDetailPageRenderer`. Also I assumed that Xamarin would use the actual UWP Page's `TopAppBar` and `BottomAppBar` properties. This is not the case.

With the following `MasterDetailPageRenderer` the top bar (with hamburger menu button and title) is tinted green while the bottom bar stays the default gray (basically the renderer just removes the `Background` binding of the StackPanel representing the top bar and sets it to Green). One problem was, that the FindName and FindByName methods were not working (always returned null), so I had to roll my own implementations using the VisualTreeHelper.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MasterDetailPage), typeof(CustomMasterDetailPageRender))]
public class CustomMasterDetailPageRender : MasterDetailPageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MasterDetailPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Element != null)
        {                
            Element.Appearing += Element_Appearing;                         
        }
    }

    private void Element_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as MasterDetailPage).Appearing -= Element_Appearing;

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var topBarArea = FindElementByName(Control, "TopCommandBarArea");
            if (topBarArea != null)
            {
                var topContent = FindElementByType<StackPanel>(topBarArea);
                if (topContent != null)
                {
                    topContent.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                }
            }          
        }
    }

    static DependencyObject FindElementByName(DependencyObject parent, string name)
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            var sub = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (sub is FrameworkElement)
            {
                if (((FrameworkElement)sub).Name == name)
                {
                    return sub;
                }
            }

            var r = FindElementByName(sub, name);
            if (r != null)
                return r;
        }

        return null;
    }

    static T FindElementByType<T>(DependencyObject parent)
        where T: DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            var sub = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

            if (sub is T)
            {
                return (T)sub;
            }

            var r = FindElementByType<T>(sub);
            if (r != null)
                return r;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```